# How to use TfvcHttpClient to find all checked out files (i.e. items with pending changes)?

Tags: c#, azure-devops, tfs, tfvc

Consider the following code, which uses the `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client` NuGet package:

```
var tfsServerUri = new Uri("<REDACTED SERVER URL>");
var credentials  = new VssCredentials(); // Default = current user account.

using var connection     = new VssConnection(tfsServerUri, credentials);
using var projectClient  = await connection.GetClientAsync<ProjectHttpClient>();
using var versionControl = await connection.GetClientAsync<TfvcHttpClient>();

var rootProject = await projectClient.GetProject("Root");

var items = await versionControl.GetItemsAsync(rootProject.Id, scopePath: "$/Root", VersionControlRecursionType.Full);

foreach (var item in items)
{
    if (item.IsPendingChange)
    {
        ... Do something with item.
```

This does correctly iterate over all the VSS items under "$/Root", and I can print out the paths.

However, `IsPendingChange` is always `false` regardless of whether the item is actually checked-out (i.e. has a pending change).

Is this a bug, or do I just misunderstand what `IsPendingChange` is supposed to be?

The documentation for [`TfvcItem.IsPendingChange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.sourcecontrol.webapi.tfvcitem.ispendingchange?view=azure-devops-dotnet#microsoft-teamfoundation-sourcecontrol-webapi-tfvcitem-ispendingchange) is completely unhelpful.

The documentation for [the Javascript version of `isPendingChange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-devops-extension-api/tfvcitem#azure-devops-extension-api-tfvcitem-ispendingchange) states that it is:

> True if there is a change pending.

so I was hoping that applied to the C# version too. But alas, it seems not...

Does anyone know of a way to use `TfvcHttpClient` to find all checked-out files?

Comment: There is the same issue on my side. The `IsPendingChange` of all my items is false, even though I have indeed checked out. I also tried this REST API [Items - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tfvc/items/get?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0#tfvcitem), the response is the content of the file instead of the `TfvcItem` mentioned in the doc.